# Installed new version of php but server still uses older version

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, php

I just upgraded to PHP 5.4.11 from 5.3.15 following this [link](http://mac.tutsplus.com/tutorials/server/upgrading-the-native-php-installation-on-os-x-mountain-lion/). After upgrading I ran php -v but it shows me following output.

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:php-5.4.11 zafar$ php -v
PHP 5.3.15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 31 2012 14:49:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

which says PHP 5.3.15. Then I issue this command /usr/local/bin/php -v which shows following output

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:/ zafar$ /usr/local/bin/php -v
PHP 5.4.11 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2013 20:10:19) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Which shows PHP 5.4.11. When I issue which php it shows me this path /usr/bin/php. I tried following to solve this issue.

1. I went to /usr/bin/php and rename that php file to php_OLD.
2. Now I made a symlink in "/usr/bin/" to "/usr/local/bin/php" file using following command

   sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/php /usr/bin/php
3. Now I issued php -v command which worked and showed new version of php.

** But when I created phpinfo.php file with phpinfo(); function. It still uses older version of PHP i.e. PHP 5.3.15. why and how can I solve this problem?**

Comment: Have you tried moving /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin in $PATH?

Comment: I haven't touch $PATH at all. How can I do this step?

Comment: When I do `echo $PATH` then it shows this output `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

Comment: you can edit default path by sudo nano /etc/paths ; move the line with /usr/local/bin above /usr/bin

Comment: It didn't work. It still shows older version in phpinfo();. however, php -v command shows new version of php.

Comment: Can you check the content of /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, search for 'LoadModule php5_module' and replace it with the new version of libphp.so. I don't know how you install php54 but if you're using homebrew, just take a look at [this page](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php)

Comment: Here is what I have my my `httpd.conf` file `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. right now I really don't know where my newer version of php is installed. How can I find where my new version is installed? I already posted the link in my post above of how I installed PHP.